# The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I have set up a new Mac (Yosemite) and installed Eclipse IDE for Android (Luna).  ADT is up to date.  Eclipse is up to date.

I have pulled down my projects from a common git repo and created the projects in the workspace automatically.  However in the problems tab, the projects all have the same error:

> The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved -
>   Unknown - Java Problem

[image]

**There are no errors in the Java Build Path properties window.**

I have cleaned all projects.  I have restarted Eclipse and still the errors remain.  The post that may be a duplicate may work for some, I have tried all remedies posted there without fixing the issue.

How do I resolve these?

Thought I had resolved this with a clean rebuild of the repo/projects, but I was wrong.

Comment: I've found I sometimes have to change the classpath, then change it back to address this problem.

Comment: @mvd Not a dupe - that does not resolve the issue, as I state in my post - cleaning does not resolve.

Comment: Those are the only errors in your Problems view? Are you sure you checked all of the tabs in the Java Build Path window (Source, Projects, Libraries, etc.)?

Comment: @EvanLaHurd Yes, currently those are the only 3 errors.

Comment: Are there any warnings? Anything useful in the console window?

Comment: Hm, usually there's a missing source folder or required project/library. You said you did try a clean, but are you sure it rebuilt, too?

Comment: @EvanLaHurd  It's not building, but I am not sure why.  Java Build Path looks clean (no missing references).  Something very strange going on though.

Comment: To me this looks like a JDK error. Check Eclipse->Preferences->Installed JREs and make sure it's pointing to the correct place.

Comment: Also right click on the project - > Properties -> Project Facets and make sure that eclipse knows what type of project it's dealing with.

Comment: @ventsyv  - I don't have a `project facets` option as you describe the path to.

Comment: That might be missing from ADT. Did you verify that you JRE is set up correctly?

Comment: @ventsyv - Yes please see my updated post.